# How can I add values under an equation using Word equation tools?

Tags: microsoft-word, equation-editor

Good morning. Please could you tell me of some method to add values within parentheses under a mathematical expression using the Word equation tools other than using 
\matrix = ■(y_t=&(1.3771&+&0.7977y_(t-1))I_t&+&(1-I_t )(1.6015&+&0.2545y_(t-1))@&(2.60)&&(10.10)&&(7.22)&&(2.72) )

This is the result when using a Matrix placeholder:

[image: Matrix view]

Or \below y_t=(〖1.3771〗┬((2.60) )+〖0.7977〗┬((10.10) ) y_(t-1) ) I_t+(1-I_t )(〖1.6015〗┬((7.22) )+〖0.2545〗┬((2.72) ) y_(t-1) )

This is the result using "below":

[image: below]

That is to say, I want to see the values under each corresponding number as it appears in the attached image, which are highlighted in red.

This is what I would like to achieve:

[image: desired result]

Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the nearest I could manage (Word 365/2019):

```
\eqarray(y_t=&"("1.377l&+&0.7977y_(t-1) ")"I_t&+(1-I_t )&"("1.6015&+&0.2545y_(t-1) ")"@&\rect ((2.60))&&\rect ((10.10))&&\rect ((7.22))&&\rect ((2.72)))
```

If that has to be one element inside a matrix, I would probably need to look again.

As you can see I had to use "" to make the ( and ) characters into literals to get build-up to stop treating them as pairs and ignoring the & characters between them. Trying to use the escape `\(` doesn't seem to work as buildup insists on adding space.

I don't know how to show how I coloured the rectangles red in here, if that's what you are attempting, but in the linear format I ensured I was seeing

```
\rect ((2.60))
```

and I used Home->Font and the color dropdown to appy Red.

If you don't want the rectangles, omit the `\rect()` sequences, but as usual you may need to insert some spaces at various points to make "build-up" work properly.

Comment: Thank you very much for your valuable answer, really the numbers in parenthesis inside the red boxes were just an example of what I'm really looking for, in my case I'll just omit the \rect() command, your explanation is quite useful to me! Thanks again for your collaboration.

Comment: @CamillaSanchez Thanks!

Comment: Your guidance has been very helpful, now I would like you to please guide me to solve another problem that has arisen when trying to incorporate an equation using the equation matrix. I am going to formulate a new topic to propose in more detail the doubt that has come to me, I hope you can help me, thank you!